# Type bound issue using Quartz from Scala

Tags: scala, quartz-scheduler, scala-java-interop, type-bounds

I am trying to reschedule a job and I have defined my method like so :

```
  private def updateTriggerInterval(context: JobExecutionContext): Unit = {
    val randomInterval = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min
    val oldTrigger: Trigger = context.getTrigger
    val up: TriggerBuilder[SimpleTrigger] = oldTrigger.getTriggerBuilder.withSchedule[SimpleTrigger](simpleSchedule()
       .withIntervalInMinutes(randomInterval).repeatForever())

    val scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler
    scheduler.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getKey, up.build())
  }
```

This gives me the following error :

> Error:(33, 55) type arguments [org.quartz.SimpleTrigger] do not
>   conform to method withSchedule's type parameter bounds [SBT <: ?0]
>       val up = oldTrigger.getTriggerBuilder.withScheduleSimpleTrigger.build()

Now looking at the signature of `withSchedule` :

```
public <SBT extends T> TriggerBuilder<SBT> withSchedule(ScheduleBuilder<SBT> schedBuilder)
```

`T` is a type parameter on the class of `withSchedule` which looks like `class TriggerBuilder<T extends Trigger>`. So `T` should be defined by the type parameter of the instance returned by `getTriggerBuilder`, which here should be `TriggerBuilder<SimpleTrigger> getTriggerBuilder()`, so `T` is a `SimpleTrigger`. In the `Trigger` interface `getTriggerBuilder` is defined like so :  `TriggerBuilder<? extends Trigger> getTriggerBuilder()`.`simpleSchedule` returns a `SimpleScheduleBuilder` (which extends `ScheduleBuilder<SimpleTrigger>`).

What I'm understanding here is that `SBT` (i.e `SimpleTrigger` too if we look at the error) should extends a class that extends `Trigger`. Problem here is we have `SimpleTrigger <: SimpleTrigger`. Totally not sure I read this right though.

If I do not type `withSchedule` I end up with the same error, plus this one :

> Error:(37, 46) type mismatch;  found   :
>   org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder  required:
>   org.quartz.ScheduleBuilder[SBT]
>         .withIntervalInMinutes(randomInterval).repeatForever)

```
                                         ^
```

Can somebody help me out here ? For the record the [official Quartz example](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/UpdateTrigger) isn't compiling either (same error).

Comment: What's the type `T` for `Trigger`, and what's the result type of `simpleSchedule()`. Looks to me like some ugliness coming from Java's use-site variance. For that in Scala you usually need existential types, like `withSchedule[_ <: SimpleTrigger]`. Not sure

Comment: @0__ Updated question. Existential type gives me "unbounded wildcard type".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, just made it work by casting oldTrigger to SimpleTrigger... That turned `TriggerBuilder<? extends Trigger> getTriggerBuilder()` into `TriggerBuilder<SimpleTrigger> getTriggerBuilder()`.